# WiX Burn installer doesn't install or uninstall after one successful attempt

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.10

WiX Burn installer is not uninstalling or installing after one successful attempt. I was able to ssuccessfully install. Then I successfully uninstalled it. But again when I tried to run the installer, nothing happens. It launches and closes immediately. Below is the log entries I have.

```
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i001: Burn v3.10.2.2516, Windows v10.0 (Build 10240: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{4FD11131-BF57-4BB2-A033-6276C427B817}\.cr\TestAppsPlatformSetup.exe
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallLoc' to value 'C:\Program Files\'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i000: Initializing string variable 'ManagerName' to value ''
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i000: Initializing string variable 'OriginalLocation' to value '[WixBundleOriginalSource]'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i009: Command Line: '"-burn.clean.room=G:\Projects\Test 2.0\Test-installer\TestAppsPlatformSetup\TestPlatformSetup\bin\Release\TestAppsPlatformSetup.exe"'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'G:\Projects\Test 2.0\Test-installer\TestAppsPlatformSetup\TestPlatformSetup\bin\Release\TestAppsPlatformSetup.exe'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'G:\Projects\Test 2.0\Test-installer\TestAppsPlatformSetup\TestPlatformSetup\bin\Release\'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757.log'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]w055: Could not load or read state file: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{bd2d06d2-06ee-4cae-94a1-fd3f2b464de1}\\state.rsm, error: 0x80070003.
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'TestAppsPlatformSetup'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Zone24x7'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[327C:3638][2017-05-03T20:27:57]i000: Launching custom TestBA UX
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i100: Detect begin, 5 packages
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Setting numeric variable 'JavaInstalled_x64' to value 1
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i102: Detected related bundle: {d08b5cdc-a047-4a08-852c-3b8113791164}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.254.0.0, operation: None
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Detecting related bundle and status None
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i101: Detected package: TestAppsInstallerId, state: Absent, cached: None
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i101: Detected package: TestBarcodeInstallerId, state: Absent, cached: None
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i101: Detected package: TestRFIDInstallerId, state: Absent, cached: None
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i101: Detected package: TestAuxiliaryInstallerId, state: Absent, cached: None
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i101: Detected package: AppInstallerId, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Uninstall state False
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Install state True
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: About to calculate disk space 
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i200: Plan begin, 5 packages, action: Install
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_TestAppsInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_000_TestAppsInstallerId_rollback.log'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_TestAppsInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_000_TestAppsInstallerId.log'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_TestBarcodeInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_001_TestBarcodeInstallerId_rollback.log'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_TestBarcodeInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_001_TestBarcodeInstallerId.log'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_TestRFIDInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_002_TestRFIDInstallerId_rollback.log'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_TestRFIDInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_002_TestRFIDInstallerId.log'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_TestAuxiliaryInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_003_TestAuxiliaryInstallerId_rollback.log'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_TestAuxiliaryInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_003_TestAuxiliaryInstallerId.log'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_AppInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_004_AppInstallerId_rollback.log'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_AppInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_004_AppInstallerId.log'
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i201: Planned package: TestAppsInstallerId, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i201: Planned package: TestBarcodeInstallerId, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i201: Planned package: TestRFIDInstallerId, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i201: Planned package: TestAuxiliaryInstallerId, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i201: Planned package: AppInstallerId, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i207: Planned related bundle: {d08b5cdc-a047-4a08-852c-3b8113791164}, type: Upgrade, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, dependency: None
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i300: Apply begin
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i000: install location is : G:\Projects\Test 2.0\Test-installer\TestAppsPlatformSetup\TestPlatformSetup\bin\Release
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x8007015e, restart: Required, ba requested restart:  No
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: InstallLoc = C:\Program Files\
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: JavaInstalled_x64 = 1
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: ManagerName = 
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: OriginalLocation = G:\Projects\Test 2.0\Test-installer\TestAppsPlatformSetup\TestPlatformSetup\bin\Release\TestAppsPlatformSetup.exe
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 0
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757.log
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_TestAppsInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_000_TestAppsInstallerId.log
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_TestAuxiliaryInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_003_TestAuxiliaryInstallerId.log
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_TestBarcodeInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_001_TestBarcodeInstallerId.log
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_TestRFIDInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_002_TestRFIDInstallerId.log
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_AppInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_004_AppInstallerId.log
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Zone24x7
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = TestAppsPlatformSetup
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = G:\Projects\Test 2.0\Test-installer\TestAppsPlatformSetup\TestPlatformSetup\bin\Release\TestAppsPlatformSetup.exe
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = G:\Projects\Test 2.0\Test-installer\TestAppsPlatformSetup\TestPlatformSetup\bin\Release\
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {bd2d06d2-06ee-4cae-94a1-fd3f2b464de1}
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_TestAppsInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_000_TestAppsInstallerId_rollback.log
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_TestAuxiliaryInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_003_TestAuxiliaryInstallerId_rollback.log
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_TestBarcodeInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_001_TestBarcodeInstallerId_rollback.log
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_TestRFIDInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_002_TestRFIDInstallerId_rollback.log
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_AppInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppsPlatformSetup_20170503202757_004_AppInstallerId_rollback.log
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessFolder = G:\Projects\Test 2.0\Test-installer\TestAppsPlatformSetup\TestPlatformSetup\bin\Release\
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessPath = G:\Projects\Test 2.0\Test-installer\TestAppsPlatformSetup\TestPlatformSetup\bin\Release\TestAppsPlatformSetup.exe
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 1.254.0.0
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

Only error I find is this.

```
[327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:57]w055: Could not load or read state file: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{bd2d06d2-06ee-4cae-94a1-fd3f2b464de1}\\state.rsm, error: 0x80070003.
```

Is this the reason? If so what should I do to overcome this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> [327C:1C70][2017-05-03T20:27:58]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x8007015e, restart: Required, ba requested restart:  No

[winerror.h 0x8007015e](http://errco.de/win32/winerror-h/error_fail_noaction_reboot/0x8007015e/)

```
#define ERROR_FAIL_NOACTION_REBOOT
No action was taken as a system reboot is required.
```

Comment: But I have not enabled system reboot for any of the MsiPackage elements in my Bundle.wxs. Any idea why the bundle is waiting for a system restart? :(

Comment: You can get into this state if your install ignores reboot return codes and just proceeds as if everything finished normally. This doesn't change the fact that the Windows OS is now in a state where no installers will run because a reboot is required.

Comment: Or anything that causes a pending reboot, like an update.

Comment: @BrianSutherland I still don't understand how the installer would return a reboot code as I have not done that at any phase? Would be great if you can elaborate a little on this :(

Comment: @BobArnson This does happen when I am trying to update an already wxisting burn bundle. But I still don't understand why it needs a restart without me specifying one for any of the MSIs in the bundle :(

Comment: It's saying that a reboot was already pending when the bundle ran, not that a package caused a pending reboot.